# Use Resources With Array Elements in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin forms and what to define two content views as a static resources to be used as a Sync Fusion Rotator views and here's the code

```
 <contentViews:BarcodeScanningWindow x:Key="vwScanItem" Text="{Binding ItemName}" Image="{Binding ItemImage}"></contentViews:BarcodeScanningWindow>
 <contentViews:BarcodeScanningWindow x:Key="vwScanLocation" Text="{Binding LocationName}" Image="{Binding LocationImage}"></contentViews:BarcodeScanningWindow>

 <x:Array x:Key="BarcodeWnds" Type="{x:Type xForms:SfRotatorItem}">
      <xForms:SfRotatorItem ItemContent="{StaticResource vwScanItem}"></xForms:SfRotatorItem>
      <xForms:SfRotatorItem ItemContent="{StaticResource vwScanLocation}"></xForms:SfRotatorItem>
 </x:Array>
```

However, each time I run I get this error

> Position 38:24. StaticResource not found for key Content

I tried creating another array with Style type this time and still received the same error, so I'm guessing the problem is using static resources with array elements. 
Does anyone know how to do it?